# Persistent BSOD

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod

I'm having this BSOD error for the past year. It's exactly the same every time I analyzed it using WinDBG. I can't seem to find the root cause... I turned on driver verifier but they all checked out. but couldn't find a problem driver. Please help.

```
DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 0000000000000258, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: fffffa80036e1b50, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: fffff80000b9a3d0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_PNP on Win7 and higher

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now fffffa80`036e1b50

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  4

FAULTING_THREAD:  fffffa80036e1b50

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFFF80000BA0FB0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80003168156 to fffff800030d2400

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00b9a398 fffff800`03168156 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000258 fffffa80`036e1b50 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9a3a0 fffff800`0331a34c : fffffa80`00000000 fffff800`00000000 fffff800`00b9ab00 00000000`00000004 : nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+0x76
fffff800`00b9a400 fffff800`030ddd4c : fffff800`00b9a4c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 fffff980`03076f00 : nt!PopBuildDeviceNotifyListWatchdog+0x1c
fffff800`00b9a430 fffff800`030ddbe6 : fffffa80`051b1b30 00000000`000446c3 00000000`00000000 fffff880`02e0c0b5 : nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable+0x6c
fffff800`00b9a4a0 fffff800`030ddace : 0000000a`2df61960 fffff800`00b9ab18 00000000`000446c3 fffff800`03255ae8 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0xc6
fffff800`00b9aaf0 fffff800`030dd8b7 : 00000003`465241c3 00000003`000446c3 00000003`46524128 00000000`000000c3 : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9ab90 fffff800`030ca10a : fffff800`03251e80 fffff800`0325fcc0 00000000`00000000 fffff880`00000000 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9ac40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`00b9b000 fffff800`00b95000 fffff800`00b9ac00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xfffffa80036e1b50 ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+76
fffff800`03168156 cc              int     3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+76

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5708972e

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.23418

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_4_nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+76

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x9F_4_nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+76

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x9f_4_nt!pnpbugcheckpowertimeout+76

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {66f5e344-0be0-6fcb-cd7e-04c13e9ff0ff}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

It happens about once a week. It's happened yesterday and today. Random, sometimes when no applications are open.

Here's a link to the dumps, as well as list of drivers and system info:
http://www.filedropper.com/qa-reports2-thu0616201610081278

Comment: how frequently does the BSoD happen? Is it once a day, a few times a day, once a week? Also, does it also happen if you don't do it, or use different programs?

Comment: share the dmp file (onedrive, dropbox)

Comment: hm, Microsoft doesn't provide the TRIAGE_9F_PNP data so we can't dump parameter 4 to see more details. Try to disable power saving for several devices in device manager and also try to set powerplan to "High Performance"

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: also try to update the Intel driver igdkmd64.sys. Your driver is from 2014 (Jan 22 23:42:16 2014)

Answer (score 0):

1 dump shows tat the Intel HD driver `igdkmd64.sys` is involved

```
               rsp : 0xfffff80000b9a398 : 0xfffff8000310c156 : nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+0x76
0xfffff80000b9a398 : 0xfffff8000310c156 : nt!PnpBugcheckPowerTimeout+0x76
0xfffff80000b9a3d8 : 0xfffff8000327fa00 : nt!PnpDeviceCompletionQueue
0xfffff80000b9a3e0 : 0xfffff800032202d8 : nt!ExWorkerQueue+0x58
0xfffff80000b9a3f8 : 0xfffff800032be34c : nt!PopBuildDeviceNotifyListWatchdog+0x1c
0xfffff80000b9a418 : 0xfffff8000307ed3a : nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x15a
0xfffff80000b9a428 : 0xfffff80003081d4c : nt!KiProcessTimerDpcTable+0x6c
0xfffff80000b9a430 : 0xfffff88005583000 : dxgmms1!VidSchiSubmitRenderCommand+0xa50
0xfffff80000b9a448 : 0xfffff8800549b000 : dxgkrnl!DxgkCddOpenResource+0x90
0xfffff80000b9a450 : 0xfffff880054be000 : dxgkrnl!DXGCONTEXT::PresentFromCdd+0x1e0
0xfffff80000b9a460 : 0xfffff88005585000 : dxgmms1!VidSchiAdjustWorkerThreadPriority+0x128
0xfffff80000b9a468 : 0xfffff88005584000 : dxgmms1!VidSchiSendToExecutionQueueWithWait+0x180
0xfffff80000b9a470 : 0xfffff800031f5e80 : nt!KiInitialPCR+0x180
0xfffff80000b9a490 : 0xfffff80000b9a4f8 : 0xfffff8800555268b : dxgmms1!VidSchiProcessIsrCompletedPacket+0x1eb
0xfffff80000b9a498 : 0xfffff80003081be6 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0xc6
0xfffff80000b9a4a0 : 0xfffff8000321cf80 : nt!PpmCheckTimer
0xfffff80000b9a4b8 : 0xfffff880055560b5 : dxgmms1!VidSchiUpdateContextRunningTimeAtISR+0x45
0xfffff80000b9a4c8 : 0xfffff800032be330 : nt!PopBuildDeviceNotifyListWatchdog
0xfffff80000b9a4d8 : 0xfffff8000321cfc0 : nt!PpmCheckStartDpc
0xfffff80000b9a4e0 : 0xfffff8000316e900 : nt!PpmCheckStart
0xfffff80000b9a4f8 : 0xfffff8800555268b : dxgmms1!VidSchiProcessIsrCompletedPacket+0x1eb
0xfffff80000b9a518 : 0xfffff880055a17a8 : HDAudBus!HDABusWmiLogETW+0x248
0xfffff80000b9a588 : 0xfffff88005552192 : dxgmms1!VidSchDdiNotifyInterruptWorker+0x1ea
0xfffff80000b9a5e8 : 0xfffff880055944b6 : HDAudBus!HdaController::Isr+0x596
0xfffff80000b9a668 : 0xfffff80003072067 : nt!KiScanInterruptObjectList+0x77
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for igdkmd64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for igdkmd64.sys
0xfffff80000b9a6b0 : 0xfffff80003071e43 : nt!KiChainedDispatch+0x133
0xfffff80000b9a7a8 : 0xfffff8800555a1d3 : dxgmms1!VidSchiInterlockedInsertTailList+0x47
0xfffff80000b9a7f8 : 0xfffff8800555577c : dxgmms1!VidSchiFreeQueuePacket+0xa4
0xfffff80000b9a848 : 0xfffff88005554396 : dxgmms1!VidSchiProcessCompletedQueuePacketInternal+0x44e
0xfffff80000b9a898 : 0xfffff8000307a3e6 : nt!KeSetEvent+0x106
0xfffff80000b9a8b8 : 0xfffff8800555649f : dxgmms1!VidSchiSignalRegisteredEvent+0xe7
```

Your igdkmd64.sys is from 2014:

```
0: kd> lmvm igdkmd64
start             end                 module name        
    Loaded symbol image file: igdkmd64.sys
    Image path: igdkmd64.sys
    Image name: igdkmd64.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Jan 22 23:42:16 2014
```

So go to [Intel and download the latest driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics).

Answer (score -1):

Use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to read the dumps. It will show the most likely driver/dll that causes BSOD.

According to my experience, 0x9F usually refers to Intel LAN adapter driver/Intel Display driver. BSOD happens when they try to change power mode/enter sleep mode. Drive update is required.

You can use https://drp.su/index.htm to scan you PC for available driver updates.

Comment: no, the tool is crap, shows nonsense and shows ntoskrnl.exe as "cause"

Comment: @magicandre1981 disagree, in many cases it showed me the real dll referring to a driver

Comment: no, 99.9% it shows nonsense

Comment: @magicandre1981 At least my answer gives a reference what 0x9F is related and a real advise how to update all drivers quickly. So, I don't think it should be downvoted!

Comment: if you tried bluescreenview with his dumps you would noticed that it shows ntkernel and doesn't help.

Comment: it shows ntkernel if it is not a definite driver, you have a bad experience with it. we have 25000+ pcs and about 500 bsods per month in our company. I know what to compare with